# Can I do a wildcard (*) search on github.com?

Tags: search, github, wildcard

I want to search a repository for any files that end in `*Test.java*` but if I search for `*Test.java*` I just get files that contain that exact string.

I can't find any information anywhere that suggests this is possible. Is this just due to limitations of indexing such an enormous amount of data?

I'd like to find a way to search a repo for all classes ending in `Test`.

Comment: You might want to try out the filefinder by pressing `T` in the Tree view and entering your search.

Comment: Tree view? Are you talking about the github website here?

Comment: I do. Open this page: https://github.com/mirrors/linux/ and then hit the `T` key on your keyboard.

Comment: @TimWolla was right. You should post this as an answer because it's the right one.

Comment: It's good, but not quite right. Still doesn't allow a proper wildcard search - beginning with, ending with etc. I guess it just doesn't exist!

Comment: @slugmandrew It does do wildcards. It uses regular expressions. See the new edit to my answer below.

Comment: It's not the same thing though. Say I want to find files that start with `My` and end in `Test.java` I type `My*Test.java` which should then return `MyFirstTest.java`, `MySecondTest.java` etc. The regex results are clearly very useful though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the GitHub site, and not directly programming related.

Comment: @slugmandrew Just type MyTest.java and it'll return both. :)

Comment: @Abizern I disagree. The GitHub site is a tool used widely by programmers. Locating files is sure to be of interest to many programmers.

Comment: Interest, yes. Directly programming related, no. We all use computers yet hardware questions aren't on-topic. We all use Search Engines, but I'd vote to close questions about using those.

Comment: @mttdbrd Yes it will, but it will also return anything else with an `m` and a `y` in the path/filename :P

Comment: @Abizern Sheesh. Should I have posted it in webapps or superuser then? What do you suggest?

Comment: Github has a support page. What next? questions about posting code snippets on Twitter? Another tool widely used by programmers.

Comment: @mttdbrd I just added my answer about the file finder. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to find a file in a repository is to use the file finder. You can activate it at any time when you are in repository view by pressing <kbd>t</kbd>. See this screenshot from the [official annoucement](https://github.com/blog/793-introducing-the-file-finder):

[image]

The file finder will perform some fuzzy matching using the characters you input into the "search box".

Comment: In another words, the answer should be: *No, you can not.*

Answer (score 6):

Check out the search syntax page:

https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax

And searching in repositories:

https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories

For this particular one:

```
Test.java in:name extension:java language: java
```

**Edit 1:**

Here's a picture to explain how to view code matches instead of repository matches:

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Turns out the comment above was right. This is what the GitHub people say:

> Hi,
>
> The easiest method for finding files within a repository is to use the
> file finder:
>
> https://github.com/blog/793-introducing-the-file-finder
>
> You can also use the "in:" search qualifier which allows you to tell
> search to match filenames as well:
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code#search-in
>
> Hope that helps!

**Edit 3:**

Although it doesn't use wildcards as we're used to, it uses regular expressions to find substrings of the strings you type. See below, I typed "SandTest.java" and it produced wild-card like results.

[image]

Comment: Hmm. `Test.Java in:name` actually searched for repositories with test in the repository name. I need something like `Test.java in:filename` bit it seems that for code there is only the options to search the path or file contents, not the actual filename itself: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code

Comment: extension:java searches filenames with .java extension. Now to restrict it to just files with that name....

Comment: Test in:name extension:java language:java returns a lot of stuff, not necessarily restricted to Java....

Comment: It's strange huh? It seems that the engine is mainly geared for searching for actual lines of code, or whole repos.

Comment: It's odd. Even Google won't find an exact filename on site:github.com. It finds all kinds of other stuff. It seems like filenames are excluded from full-text search; it only searches file contents.

Comment: I think you should give me an upvote for such an excellent question ;)

Comment: Done. It's a tough one.

Comment: @slugmandrew Oh, wait. If you click the "<> Code" item in the box on the upper left of the page instead of "[] Repositories" you get just files. This gets a lot of them: Test.java in:name extension:java language:java. There's still extra garbage because some people have "test.java" packages and files named "TestJava." Finds over 4,000,000 files.

Comment: @slugmandrew And how about an upvote, you know, for the effort?

Comment: I actually just want to search a single repo. This https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/search?q=test+in%3Aname isn't too bad, but it's still finding the class names inside the files rather than the filenames themselves.

Comment: @slugmandrew I put in a help request at GitHub. I've had this exact problem before. I'll let you know what they say.

Comment: @slugmandrew See the new edit above. There's a new file-finder. TimWalla was right!

Comment: @slugmandrew To use it, you go to the repository and without clicking in the search box, just type t. It takes you to a new page. Without clicking anything there, just type Test.java. Magic!

Comment: There is: in:path in:path,file (in:file is the default). I find "in:path" does not work at the org-level (org:abc) without extension:abc. in-syntax: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code#search-by-the-file-contents-or-file-path

Comment: There is also: path:abc and filename:abc (which work at org-level eg org:abc) https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code#search-by-file-location