# How I could get back partial search results inside a GitHub repo?

Tags: github

When I am searching for example 'CGLI' it does not gives me back the matches for 'CGLIB':

https://github.com/SquareSquash/java/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=CGLI

How can I force to give it back?

Comment: What in the world are you asking?

Comment: He wants a wildcard search for `CGLI*` I believe.

Comment: yes thats correct, I am searching for a way for wildcard or regex search

Comment: Here's how to use wildcard for files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714654/can-i-do-a-wildcard-search-on-github-com

Comment: yes, I know that, I wanna search instead for the content

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on advanced search on the search tab, that will do what you want:

https://github.com/search?l=&q=CGLI&ref=advsearch&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

But:

> You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search
>   query: . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ]. The
>   search will simply ignore these symbols.
>   https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/

Comment: yes, this way the partial results are showing up as well, thanks

Comment: By the way this could be a github bug. I really not see what could be the reason that only advanced search support substring matching.